# mezzanine overextends tag return empty template

Tags: django, mezzanine

I'm trying to use mezzanine's overextends tag to both override and extends the existing template which comes with mezzanine.

What it basically does is that it removes the current template itself by removing itself from the list of templates while looking for available templates so that one can *overextend* a template by using the same name without having `circular reference`.

I am aware of that there are other ways to resolve the problem, yet I don't want to write a view which renders a different template *(with a different name)* when I just want to change a new `block` tag in the template.

In the documentation it says that I can just use it as I would use `extends` tag, but when I do that, it just return me an empty template.

Here is my project structure:

```
project_dir
-|blog
--|__init___.py
--|templates
---|blog_post_detail.html
---|blog_post_list.html
-|override
--|__init__.py
--|admin.py
--|templatetags
---|__init__.py
---|extensive_tags.py
```

Here is sample template which does not work:

```
{% overextends "blog/blog_post_list.html" %}
{% load mezzanine_tags extensive_tags i18n %}
{% block right_panel %}
{% get_best_posts_for_category blog_post 3 as best_posts %}
{%if best_posts %}
<ul class="nav nav-list">
    <li class="nav-header">BU KATEGORİDEKİ EN İYİ POSTLAR</li>
    {% for best_post in best_posts %}
    <li>
        <a href="{{ best_post.get_absolute_url }}">{{ best_post.title }} ({{ best_post.rating_average }})</a>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Here is the `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    "blog",
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.redirects",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.sites",
    "django.contrib.sitemaps",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "mezzanine.boot",
    "mezzanine.conf",
    "mezzanine.core",
    "mezzanine.generic",
    "mezzanine.blog",
    "mezzanine.forms",
    "mezzanine.pages",
    "mezzanine.galleries",
    "mezzanine.accounts",
    "override",
)
```

and `TEMPLATE_DIRS` in `settings.py`:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "templates"),)
```

What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed in the dev branch but not yet released. I've just released 1.1.3 which contains the fix, so if you upgrade this should work.